# Please tell me where i am wrom how to correct it :

Tags: c#

i used three tier architecture
System.IndexOutOfRangeException:
enter code here There is no row at position 1. here with i paste my code here

## data layer

The data acess layer

```
 public DataSet getRecordDisplay(int product_id,int category_id)
            {
                string constring = string.Empty;
    
                SqlConnection conn;
    
    
                constring = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["MyConnection"].ConnectionString;
                conn = new SqlConnection(constring);
                conn.Open();
                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sp_Productselect", conn);
                cmd.CommandText = "sp_Productselect";
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@product_id", DbType.Int32).Value = product_id;
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@category_id", DbType.Int32).Value = category_id;
                SqlDataAdapter adpt = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
                DataSet dst = new DataSet();
                adpt.Fill(dst);
                return dst;
    
            }

#Business logic
```

Business logic layer is enclosed here

```
 public DataSet getRecordDisplay(int product_id,int category_id)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = dal.getRecordDisplay(product_id,category_id);
            return ds;
        }

# code behind
 

     int product_id = Convert.ToInt32(txtPId.Text);
                int category_id = Convert.ToInt32(txtctid.Text);
                DataSet dsOrderDetail = new DataSet();
               
    
                        dsOrderDetail = bal.getRecordDisplay(product_id, category_id);
                    lblProdName.Text = dsOrderDetail.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Product_Name"].ToString() + "<br/>";
                    lblProdId.Text = dsOrderDetail.Tables[0].Rows[1]["Product_Id"].ToString() + "<br/>";
                    lblProdDesc.Text = dsOrderDetail.Tables[0].Rows[2]["Description"].ToString() + "<br/>";
                    lblCtyId.Text = dsOrderDetail.Tables[0].Rows[3]["Category_id"].ToString() + "<br/>";
                    lblPrice.Text = dsOrderDetail.Tables[0].Rows[4]["Price"].ToString() + "<br/>";
                    lblAblty.Text = dsOrderDetail.Tables[0].Rows[5]["Availability"].ToString() + "<br/>";

#my stored procedure


stored procedure is added here
        GO
            CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Productselect] 
            @product_id as int,
            @category_id as  int
        AS
        BEGIN
         
            SELECT * FROM product04 where   product_id=345 and category_id=2346
        END
        
        GO
```

Comment: The exception is pretty clear. You are trying to read data from a position that doesn't exist. Most likely because you try to read data from 6 rows instead of only one row.

Comment: If you had an array containing three items like this `string[3]` and you tried to access the 4th position you would get an `index out of range` error. You're doing the same, you're trying to access an index that doesn't exist. We can't tell where from the code you've provided, you don't even tell us on which line the error occurs...

Comment: You should *highly* consider renaming your stored procedure.  Calling procedures named with a `sp_` prefix, regardless of what database you are currently targeting, will always check the `master` database first for that procedure, and *then* look in the database you're targeting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You also need to check query is returning data or not , you are facing issue because you are trying to access datarow data which is not present. I hope you got my point.

```
 dsOrderDetail = bal.getRecordDisplay(product_id, category_id);

if(dsOrderDetail !=null && dsOrderDetail.Table.Count > 0 && dsOrderDetail.Table.Rows.Count >0)
{
     lblProdName.Text = dsOrderDetail.Tables[0].Rows[0]["Product_Name"].ToString() + "<br/>";
     lblProdId.Text = dsOrderDetail.Tables[0].Rows[1]["Product_Id"].ToString() + "<br/>";
     lblProdDesc.Text = dsOrderDetail.Tables[0].Rows[2]["Description"].ToString() + "<br/>";
     lblCtyId.Text = dsOrderDetail.Tables[0].Rows[3]["Category_id"].ToString() + "<br/>";
     lblPrice.Text = dsOrderDetail.Tables[0].Rows[4]["Price"].ToString() + "<br/>";
     lblAblty.Text = dsOrderDetail.Tables[0].Rows[5]["Availability"].ToString() + "<br/>";
}
```

there is issue with you stored procedure

```
SELECT * FROM product04 where   product_id=345 and category_id=2346
```

instead of this line of query it should be

```
  CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[sp_Productselect] 
        @product_id as int,
        @category_id as  int
    AS
    BEGIN

        SELECT * FROM product04 where   product_id=@product_id and category_id=@category_id 
    END

    GO
```

there are other thing in you code , you should use "using" for connection to dispose it.

```
 public DataSet getRecordDisplay(int product_id,int category_id)
{
 ...
  using( SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionstring))
  {
  }
 ...
}
```